# WordPress - get_posts containing category

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to obtain a list of posts containing a specific category (in this case $category_id):

`$categorized_posts = get_posts(array('category' => $category_id));`

Problem is this function will return only posts having that category AS first category, but posts can have even 6 categories and this one can be first, second or even last.

Is there a way to match posts CONTAINING category and not having CATEGORY as "main category"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by obtaining the entire list of posts, then filtering them.
The operation is heavy, but at the moment seems the only way to do it.